# Trigger mouseover event on button on page load, extjs3

Tags: button, triggers, extjs3

I have a `button` with `tooltip`, I want to show the `tooltip` on pageload for few seconds. Using `EXTJS 3`

Can I trigger the mousehover event on page load or any other solution can I have?

Comment: Been awhile since I messed with ExtJS 3 but I'd imagine you could put an afterrender listener on the button, and when that fires you can show the tooltop and do a setTimeout in order to hide it after a few seconds. I would think you would get the tooltip and explicitly show/hide it rather than trying to simulate the mousehover event.

Answer (score 1):

Try with below code snippet on `render` event:

```
var tip = new Ext.ToolTip({
    target: c.getEl(),
    html: 'Tooltip content'
});
tip.showBy(this.getEl());
```

[Working example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ibq)